# Unable to establish RDP connection with XRDP

Tags: server, 18.04, xfce, remote-desktop

I have installed `Ubuntu 18.04.2` and installed `xrdp` package on it and set `xfce` as desktop environment.
When I try to use RDP from Windows I got a login screen with 3 input fields, where session is set to `Xorg` by default. I typed username and password, but got a blank screen and connection is closed after a few seconds.

If I set `X11rdp` as session, I get following error message after a few minutes.

[image: x11rdp error message]

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@vivekteega/how-to-setup-an-xrdp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-89f7e205bd4e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : Sept 2019

looks like same issue as [18.04.3 LTS XRDP "login failed for display: 0"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164456/18-04-3-lts-xrdp-login-failed-for-display-0/1177330#1177330)

known issue with xRDP and Ubuntu 18.04.2.  Performing xrdp installation on ubuntu 18.04.2 does not intall xorgxrdp package because dependencies are not met......

To fix this......

**Best option -  Install the new xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package**

Install the new xorgxrdp package by issuing the following command

> sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04

This should fix your issue

**Quick and Dirty fix - Downgrade to xorg-xserver-core packages**

We assume that you have already installed xRDP package and you want to fix it

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
>
> sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all

More info on http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390

**Other option - use xrdp installer script to automate your installation**

*Note : To use this option, please remove the xrdp package you have installed*

You can automate the xrdp installation and have it working nicely with Ubuntu Default Desktop using one of the following scripts

> To use Ubuntu repository packages, read instructions and download the
> script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13933
>
> To compile from source (easy
> way), read instructions and download the script at
> http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13663

Hope this help

Till next time

See ya

Comment: sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04  gets ERROR:  Couldn't find any package by glob 'xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04'

Comment: which version of Ubuntu 18.04 are you running ?  ubuntu 18.04.1, 18.04.2... the initial Ubuntu release had no hwe stack package available....can you ensure that your ubuntu 18.04 is up to date.....Provide us output of lsb_release -a

Comment: @Jdawiz,  you can perform custom installation so solve your issue...or you can download the "missing" package directly from ubuntu packages web site.  Additional info, we have installed a fresh ubuntu 18.04.5 and we can find the xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package.... We have also replied to your comments you have sent to us directly.... hope this helpful

Comment: I replied to you on your site with all my details.  I am using 18.0.4.5 and my repositories are all updated.  I tried everything except the script with the custom option.  I think I am missing dependencies. xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 & xorg-video-abi-24

Comment: @jdawiz, I have seen your comments...will provide feedback and support based on the info provided.  If we can fix this issue; I will then share the solution here.... till next time....see ya