# Ubuntu 18.04.03 with xvnc or xrdp connection problem

Tags: xubuntu, vnc, xrdp, rdp

I wanted to connect remotely via RDP or VNC to an Ubuntu server with xubuntu-desktop installed. I tried the last 12h to fix this.

I installed both services and started them up and checked if they are active. 
RDP wasn't complicated an for VNC I followed some more advanced instructions for gnome.

I checked ports 3350, 3389, 6001 and 5901.
All are on "listening".

When I try to connect via Windows Remote Desktop I get to this log in screen (link down below) but if I log in with a user account it just crashes during the setup of the connection.

No matter if I select some other methods than xorg (for example: xvnc, x11rdp, any-vnc or session-man) the log always says "failed" for some reason or it crashes.

[image: Screen shot]

Connecting via VNC with an android-vnc-viewer app (x.x.x.x:5901) I get to a grey screen with a cursor and can move it around but I can do nothing else.

Same result when I choose the vnc-any option at the login screen in the pic above.

Settings I used here:

- ip: 127.0.0.1
- port: 5901
- vnc serverpw: X

I get to the grey screen with cursor and I can see the cursor of the android-vnc-viewer app moving.

Comment: The "grey screen with a cursor" sounds like you are getting X running but no desktop manager or or window manager. On a modern system the desktop manager (e.g. Gnome) would probably be what you hope and expect.

Answer (score 1):

seems to be the same issue as [18.04.3 LTS XRDP "login failed for display: 0"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164456/18-04-3-lts-xrdp-login-failed-for-display-0/1177330#1177330)

there is a **known issue with Ubuntu 18.04.2** **and 18.04.3** and xrdp package found in the repository...When you install xrdp from repository on ubuntu 18.04.2 and later, the package needs xorg-xserver-core packages while these point releases have the xorg-xserver-core-hw* packages installed

You have to either

**Best option -  Install the new xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package**

Install the new xorgxrdp package by issuing the following command

> sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04

This should fix your issue

**Downgrade xserver-xorg-core packages**

> - **downgrade** xorg-xserver-core-hw* packages to xorg-xserver-core packages and then install the xorgxrdp package

More info on http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390

**Unofficial xrdp packages compatible with Ubuntu 18.04.3**

> - use unofficial xrdp pacakge that can be used against Ubuntu 18.04.3

more info at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13455

**perform a scripted installation**

> - use one of the xrdp installer script to automate the installation

- To install from ubuntu repository,read instructions and download script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13933
- To compile from source (easy way), read instructions and download the script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13663

hope this help
Till next time