# xrdp + Xfce 4, "Login failed for display 0"

Tags: ssh, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

This is my first time (please be gentle) using Linux.

I have just received a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (without graphical interface) with just SSH added on a remote server.

I am currently trying to enable remote desktop to this server using SSH commands. (I have received username (root) and password for SSH - I am trying to use these while logging into remote desktop.)

As of this time I added all of the 4 repositories (main, universe, multiverse, restricted), successfully installed xrdp and Xfce 4 using the tutorial [How to use xRDP for remote access to Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/) (well at least I think it was successful).

My problem now is, that after establishing connection via Remote Desktop Manager (on my Windows 10) I see this:

[image: xrdp login screen]

And after filling out the username and password I see this:

[image: connection log window]

The message says:

> #### Connection Log
>
> connecting to sesman ip 128.0.0.1 port 3350
>   sesman connect ok
>   sending login info to session manager, please wait...
>   login failed for display 0

I tried to troubleshoot using this guide:
[18.04.3 LTS XRDP "login failed for display: 0"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164456/18-04-3-lts-xrdp-login-failed-for-display-0) using these lines of code:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

But to no avail.

What went wrong? What does it mean that that the login failed for display 0?

Comment: If the remote Ubuntu server does not have a monitor attached to it you might need to setup a fake display for it to work properly.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in

Comment: Did that and rebooted. Nothing changed.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu without a graphical interface, can you go back and install Ubuntu *with* a graphical interface? You really want that as a base for remote graphical logins, even if you don't need to be able to log in locally.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by clicking on *Edit* in the rdp login screen. Then click on *More Choices*, and you'll be able to select your Microsoft account, where you can enter your Ubuntu credentials.